# error message about \caption statement (was: "where is the problem")

Tags: errors, captions

[image]

Please, where is the problem?!

Comment: Please not add a picture or fragment. Instead put your complete code. Thanks.

Comment: caption can be used inside the float (i.e., Figure, Table). \begin{table} .. \end{table} for Table.

Comment: You did exactly what the error message said you did: use `\caption` outside of a floating environment. There are many similar posts on this site.

Comment: I did not understand a possible example

Comment: Your `tabular` sis  not included in a floating environment (`table` in the place of `center` would be OK).

Comment: Without `table` environment, use `\captionof{table}{Empirical...}` instead of `\caption{Empirical...}`... you need the `caption` package for that, however. And please do not post screen shots of code only

Comment: The program can be corrected Please do not know the patch

Comment: christian hupfer Thank you all for your colleagues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, a little christmas gift for you ...

Please see the following MWE (please add such an minimal working example to your next question! It is easier to help you then):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption} % <================================================

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  test & test
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{caption of table} % <=================================
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

With command `\captionof` (you need to load package `caption` for it) you can add an caption for a table or figure (second option) without using a floating `table` or `figure` ...

The result of the given MWE:

[image]